# Etymology of contrapositive and converse.

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand the origins of these terms because I always forget exactly what they mean and I think understanding the words themselves will help me memorize.

Suppose a statement if of the form: "If $P$, then $Q$." The contrapositive is given by "If $Q$ is not true, then $P$ is not true." The converse is "If $Q$, then $P$."

So I know that contra- means ${\it against}$ and con- means ${\it with}$. What about -verse and -positive? What are they referring to?

Comment: See e.g. https://books.google.ca/books?id=iuoZSkSOBQsC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57 which contains etymologies of both contrapositive and converse.

Comment: I think it helps to note that there's a fourth case, namely the inverse of a statement: "If not P, then not Q." This is logically equivalent to the converse. So the -verse's are logically equivalent, whereas the contrapositive is equivalent to the original 'positive' statement.

Comment: Awesome responses.

Answer (score 0):

*Contrapositive* comes from Latin [*contrapositum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=contrapono&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), supine of *contrapono*, *to place opposite, to oppose to*.

*Converse* comes from *conversum*, the supine of [*converto*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconverto), *to turn or whirl round, to wheel about, to cause to turn, to turn back, reverse*.